# add items of subclasses to a dictionary that expects a baseclass

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, inheritance, dictionary

```
public event EventHandler<SubEventArgs> MyEvent;

dictionary<string,EventHandler<BaseEventArgs>> Foo =new dictionary<string,EventHandler<BaseEventArgs>>();

Foo.Add("Item1" , MyEvent);
```

SubEventArgs is inherited from BaseEventArgs.

but this is not working ? how to handle this ?

Update : errors are

```
cannot convert from 'EventHandler<SubEventArgs>' to 'EventHandler<BaseEventArgs>'

The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,EventHandler<BaseEventArgs>>.Add(string, EventHandler<BaseEventArgs>)' has some invalid arguments
```

update : base and sub class

```
        public class BaseEventArgs : EventArgs
        {
            object[] data;

            public BaseEventArgs(object[] data)
            {
                this.data = data;
            }

            public BaseEventArgs(List<object> data)
            {
                this.data = data.ToArray();
            }

            public object[] Data
            {
                get
                {
                    return this.data;
                }
            }

            public bool HasData()
            {
                return this.data.Count() > 0;
            }
        }


    public class SubEventArgs : BaseEventArgs
    {


        public enum ErrorType {
            Validation = 1
            Logic = 2,
            System = 3
        };

        private ErrorType typeOfError;


        public SubEventArgs( ErrorType errorType, object[] data)
            : base(data)
        {
            this.typeOfError = errorType;
        }

        public SubEventArgs(ErrorType errorType, List<object> data)
            : base(data)
        {
            this.typeOfError = errorType;
        }


        public ErrorType TypeOfError
        {
            get
            {
                return this.typeOfError;
            }
        }



    }
```

Comment: This *has* to work. Show the declaration of `SubClass` and what error you receive from the compiler. The only error in your code so far is `dictionary` instead of `Dictionary`.

Comment: are you sure that SubClass inherits from BaseClass?

Comment: @Thousand : sorry , I updated the question .

Comment: @OndrejTucny : sorry , I updated the question

Comment: can you show your Base and SubeventArgs classes?

Comment: @Thousand : I added implementations

Comment: What you've originally posted is completely different from the code you later added to your question. Please do oversimplify when asking a question.

Comment: @OndrejTucny : sorry , I'll remember that .

Comment: Of course I meant “do *not* oversimplify”. Can't edit my original comment anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two — `EventHandler<SubEventArgs>` and `EventHandler<BaseEventArgs>` — are *completely distinct* types without any inheritance relationship. No matter that `SubEventArgs` inherits `BaseEventArgs`. So you cannot expect an instance of `EventHandler<SubEventArgs>` to be compatible with an argument of type `EventHandler<BaseEventArgs>`. Hence in the dictionary you cannot mix them together.

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the item to the base class when adding it;

(BaseClass)new SubClass()

You can then cast it back when you get it out the collection again.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Your answer is invalid in respect to the later edit of the OP's question.